# Setting up basic auth in Traefik 2.0 for use with R plumber API

Tags: docker, traefik, plumber

I'm trying to scale up my R plumber API's and starting playing with Traefik 2.0 as a means to expose, load balance, and secure the rest API's written in R. I can't get traefik to add basic auth *and* pass the path and query parameters to the container running my API. Basic auth works and I can set up the reverse proxy to the container correctly, but not both simultaneously. The setup below results in a 404 error.

I can run the containerized plumber API fine.
I can access the containerized plumber API through traefik (seen below) using the trestletech/plumber docker image through the path "api_test".
I can set up basic auth using Traefik's whoami example (seen below) and it works (ig http://localhost/traefexample/whoami).

I *can't* successfully add the two lines that are commented out below. I want those two lines to add basic auth, and while that works, I get a 404 error rather the getting the expected information.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    # The official v2.0 Traefik docker image
    image: traefik:v2.0
    # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    command:
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker

    ports:
      # The HTTP port
      - "80:80"
      - "8000:8080"
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  api_test:
    # An R plumber api in a docker container
    image: trestletech/plumber
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.api_test.rule=Path(`/api_test/{path:.+}`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.api_test-replacepathregex.replacepathregex.regex=/api_test(.*)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.api_test-replacepathregex.replacepathregex.replacement=$$1"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api_test.middlewares=api_test-replacepathregex@docker"
   #   - "traefik.http.routers.api_test.middlewares=auth"
   #   - "traefik.http.middlewares.auth.basicauth.users=user:$$apr1$$q8eZFHjF$$Fvmkk//V6Btlaf2i/ju5n/"




  traefexample:
  # A container that exposes an API to show its IP address - example from traefik basic, auth is working
    image: containous/whoami
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefexample.rule=Path(`/traefexample/{path:.+}`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefexample-replacepathregex.replacepathregex.regex=/traefexample(.*)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefexample-replacepathregex.replacepathregex.replacement=$$1"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefexample.middlewares=traefexample-replacepathregex@docker"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefexample.middlewares=auth"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.auth.basicauth.users=user:$$apr1$$q8eZFHjF$$Fvmkk//V6Btlaf2i/ju5n/"
```

With the posted setup I can use the endpoint "http://localhost/api_test/mean" and the response is the mean of some randomly selected numbers.

When I add the the two auth lines (currently commented out), I get the 404 error when I expect a single number.

Answer (score 0):

here

```
- "traefik.http.routers.api_test.middlewares=api_test-replacepathregex@docker"
```

remove `@docker` so it should be

```
- "traefik.http.routers.api_test.middlewares=api_test-replacepathregex"
```